# Пользовательская хеш-функция

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

Возник следующий вопрос при написании хеш-таблицы. Надо сделать так, чтобы ключом мог быть любой тип данных. Для использования std::unordered_map с пользовательским типом данных необходимо реализовать класс MyHashFunction, в котором переопределен оператор(), и создание объекта выглядит следующим образом: `unordered_map<MyType, int, MyHashFunction>`. Не могу разобраться, как это реализовать для своей таблицы. Как внутри нее вызывать пользовательскую хеш-функцию?

Comment: внутри чего вызывать? unordered_map сам будет использовать заданную хеш для построения таблицы,. Вам только хеш нужно написать так, чтобы вероятность равенства хеш_кодов, при разных ключей, была минимальной

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Это я понимаю, я хочу для своей реализации хеш-таблицы сделать что-то подобное. Но вот не могу разобраться, как это работает «внутри»

Comment: Во первых не называйте свою реализацию тем же именем, что и стандартная, во вторых, по мне, объяснить коротко как это все работает, вряд ли возможно. А подробно рассказано и в учебниках и в интернете найдете.

Answer (score 0):

В своем коде просто вызывайте некую функцию `size_t my_hash(T t)`. Так как Ваш класс шаблонный, то все будет "компилироваться". Напишите реализации (перегрузки) этой функции для базовых и основных типов. Когда пользователь Вашего класса захочет использовать свой тип с Вашей хеш таблицей, он получит ошибку компиляции/линковки, что нет нужной перегрузки. Он может у себя написать реализацию этой функции и все заработает.

Стандартный unordered_map именно так и реализован. Он использует [std::hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). В целом, Вы можете использовать эту функцию у себя для начала, а потом перейти на свою реализацию.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, получилось разобраться